# Software Switches vs Hardware Switches

Tags: switch, hardware

My main question is why service providers don't move to all software switches? I know the answer must be the rates, capacity and port density of the hardware switches.

So what are the difference between the throughout rate, port density supported and the capacity (in terms of memory) of hardware switches/routers, like Cisco ASR 1000 family and a software switch (OVS on DPDK) running on Intel Xeon E5 family for instance?

Comment: The Cisco ASR family is a family of routers, not switches. How do you know what the ISPs use? Each one is different, and they change equipment all the time.

Comment: You sort of answered your own question.  Hardware switches have much higher port density and forwarding rates than software based switches.  The performance of Cisco switches can be easily found in their literature.  By the way, a ASR 1000 is a router, not a switch.

Comment: @Ron: First, thanks for clarifying. Yes indeed Cisco ASRs are routers. Second, I'm aware of rates advertised by commodity switches, but is there a study or benchmark that compare (forwarding rates, etc) of software and hardware switching/routing?

Answer (score 8):

It comes down to what is accelerated through purpose-built hardware/ASICs versus what traffic flows can be punted to software/CPU for processing.

Physical switches have extremely fast switching speeds because of the purpose-built hardware ASICs meant for network switching.  A Xeon E5 can do it but will be slower since it is a general purpose chipset.

Also like others have said, physical switches are meant for high port-density for end-users/phones/servers that a virtual switch cannot match unless everything is already virtual.

That's why software routers are more popular today compared to switches as many routing tasks are typically punted to CPU anyway in software so this can be extracted from a physical router and installed in a VM.  Cisco CSR1000v is a good example of a production-ready software router for terminating VPNs, dynamic peerings, control-plane for SD-WAN, etc.

Comment: You are basically saying that performance is the main factor and I completely disagree - as you mentioned with a software router, fewer ports are typically needed so if we can't virtualise our switches, why don't we all just virtual our routers tomorrow? It's a massive change for the business. Software routers and switches are monitored differently so our NOC software needs evolving to support this, our engineers need retraining to deploy and debug virtualisation technologies, we have years of experience debugging Cisco and Juniper hardware within the company and virtually none for servers...

Comment: ...our automation tooling needs updating to deploy these software devices, how do we now respond to customer project bids (whats the time difference/cost/skill difference for building a virtual network vs a physical one?). Many software switches and routes don't have the features our hardware ones do, or the technical maturity (they're young and way more buggy). These challenges can all be overcome (us likely many are working through them) but it's nowhere near as simple of just port count or performance.

Answer (score 3):

The basic architecture of general purpose compute is just that - general purpose.  It's great at applying significant amounts of processing power to a huge variety of workloads but it doesn't truly *excel* at many of them.

As an example - GPU's are used because they're incredibly good at certain kinds of calculations and can perform the work that would equivalently be performed by dozens or hundreds of physical CPU's, all while consuming vastly less power and space while producing much less heat.  Could we build performant graphics cards out of tons of CPU's in parallel and just use software?  Probably, but it would kind of ridiculous.

The same applies to networking.  Applying the problem of how to move massive amounts of I/O in a distributed fashion also doesn't map well to an architecture where all processing is basically handled on a small number of big, central CPU's.  As impressive as the amount of bandwidth is between a CPU and main memory nowadays it's a fraction of the aggregate throughput of even a few 40GE connections.  What's worse is that outside purpose-built hardware architectures such CPU's have to process interrupts for every single packet to be forwarded.  Oh, and this is just forwarding packets - no crypto, no translation, encapsulation or other intensive processes.

Do the math on how many packets per second need to be forwarded even on a 10GE link is about 14.8 **million** per second in *one direction* (with small packets).  A basic commodity 48-port 10GE switch  has to read, process and regenerate on the order of 1.4 *billion* packets per second (..on top of any kind of control plane functions).  That's for a switch that was considered novel technology a decade ago.  At this point switches with nearly 300 **100** gigabit ports are *readily* available, with higher densities and speeds just a matter of product ship dates.

The way this has been approached is in a distributed fashion - pushing as much of that processing load to semi-autonomous processors running in dedicated silicon close to the ports themselves.  Processing terabits on a single piece of silicon is sci-fi.  Processing hundreds of gigabits on hundreds of parallel port ASIC's, though?  Done.

So why don't SP's just move the network to a bunch of Linux boxes or, better yet, push it to a public cloud?  Because all that compute can only exist in a useful way when its compute is surrounded by dedicated hardware that can feed it data (..and in turn that network hardware is only relevant because of the compute, of course).  Is there some cross-over in terms of programmability for network gear?  Absolutely.  Is there some common hardware for control planes?  Sure.  Cloud routers?  Totally.

Ultimately, though, just like the machine learning guys started on general purpose compute but have moved to GPU farms and, more recently, dedicated ASIC's so too can many basic networking tasks be run on general purpose compute (the vast majority of network gear never sees anything close to 100% utilization at any point in its life) but ultimately economics and practical engineering mean that there will always be dedicated network hardware.

(Oh - and to let you in on a dirty secret, for a very, very long time now pretty much **all** networking has been software-defined.)